Firefox fails to apply transition when element locations are set using custom CSS properties
As a proof of concept, I have created a CSS-only CodePen page with a pseudo-random number generator. This moves coloured circles to random positions on the page. The positions are stored in custom CSS properties, whose values are updated by an animation which changes the seed used for the random-number generator.
To make it more visually appealing, I added a transition to the circles, so that they will move smoothly from one position to the next.
On the latest versions of Chrome, Safari, Edge and Opera, this all works fine. In Firefox 128.0.3 (the latest version), the transitions are not applied.
Is this because transitions in Firefox do not work well with positions set by custom CSS properties? Or is there something else that I have failed to take into account?


/* A hard-coded LCG randomizer, written with CSS
 * mathematical operators. Change the value of
 * --seed to create a new set of 8 random numbers.
 * 
 * Make these numbers available as `var(--rX)`,
 * for use in property values, and as
 * `counter (rX)` for display in the `content`
 * property of `::before` and `::after`
 * pseudo-elements.
 */


 .lcg {
  --seed: 1; /* Arbitrary value. Will be changed */
  /* --a, --c and --m are good: don't change them */
  --a: 214013;
  --c: 2531011;
  --m: pow(2, 31);

  /* --r0 will change slowly as --seed changes.
   * Real randomness starts with --r1
   */
  --r0: mod(
    calc((var(--seed) * var(--a)) + var(--c)),
    var(--m)
  );

  --r1: mod(
    calc((var(--r0) * var(--a)) + var(--c)),
    var(--m)
  );

  --r2: mod(
    calc((var(--r1) * var(--a)) + var(--c)),
    var(--m)
  );

  --r3: mod(
    calc((var(--r2) * var(--a)) + var(--c)),
    var(--m)
  );

  --r4: mod(
    calc((var(--r3) * var(--a)) + var(--c)),
    var(--m)
  );

  --r5: mod(
    calc((var(--r4) * var(--a)) + var(--c)),
    var(--m)
  );

  --r6: mod(
    calc((var(--r5) * var(--a)) + var(--c)),
    var(--m)
  );
 
  --r7: mod(
    calc((var(--r6) * var(--a)) + var(--c)),
    var(--m)
  );

  counter-reset:
    r0 var(--r0)
    r1 var(--r1)
    r2 var(--r2)
    r3 var(--r3)
    r4 var(--r4)
    r5 var(--r5)
    r6 var(--r6)
    r7 var(--r7);
}

/* *********** */

:root {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* THE ANIMATION */

main.lcg {
  /* Limit left values between 0 and 800 (up to 80vw)
   * <div>s are 20vmin in diameter, so they will stay
   * in view at all times.
   */
  --p: 800;
  /* Keep top between 0 and 800 for the same reason. */
  --q: 2700000;

  --left1: calc(0.1vw *  mod(var(--r1), var(--p)));
  --left2: calc(0.1vw *  mod(var(--r2), var(--p)));
  --left3: calc(0.1vw *  mod(var(--r3), var(--p)));
  --left4: calc(0.1vw *  mod(var(--r4), var(--p)));
  --left5: calc(0.1vw *  mod(var(--r5), var(--p)));
  --left6: calc(0.1vw *  mod(var(--r6), var(--p)));
  --left7: calc(0.1vw *  mod(var(--r7), var(--p)));

  --top1: calc(0.1vh * var(--r1) / var(--q));
  --top2: calc(0.1vh * var(--r2) / var(--q));
  --top3: calc(0.1vh * var(--r3) / var(--q));
  --top4: calc(0.1vh * var(--r4) / var(--q));
  --top5: calc(0.1vh * var(--r5) / var(--q));
  --top6: calc(0.1vh * var(--r6) / var(--q));
  --top7: calc(0.1vh * var(--r7) / var(--q));

  animation-name: shuffle;
  animation-duration: 100s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


/* Checkbox to toggle animation */
.lcg:has(input:checked) {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

input ~ span::after {
  content: "Pause animation"
}

input:checked ~ span::after {
  content: "Animation paused"
}


/* Change the value of --seed 50 times per cycle.
 * The pseudo-random values for --r0 to --r7 will
 * be recalculated in a cascade.
 */
@keyframes shuffle {
  0%   { --seed:  0; }
  2%   { --seed:  1; }
  4%   { --seed:  2; }
  6%   { --seed:  3; }
  8%   { --seed:  4; }
  10%  { --seed:  5; }
  12%  { --seed:  6; }
  14%  { --seed:  7; }
  16%  { --seed:  8; }
  18%  { --seed:  9; }
  20%  { --seed: 10; }
  22%  { --seed: 11; }
  24%  { --seed: 12; }
  26%  { --seed: 13; }
  28%  { --seed: 14; }
  30%  { --seed: 15; }
  32%  { --seed: 16; }
  34%  { --seed: 17; }
  36%  { --seed: 18; }
  38%  { --seed: 19; }
  40%  { --seed: 20; }
  42%  { --seed: 21; }
  44%  { --seed: 22; }
  46%  { --seed: 23; }
  48%  { --seed: 24; }
  50%  { --seed: 25; }
  52%  { --seed: 26; }
  54%  { --seed: 27; }
  56%  { --seed: 28; }
  58%  { --seed: 29; }
  60%  { --seed: 30; }
  62%  { --seed: 31; }
  64%  { --seed: 32; }
  66%  { --seed: 33; }
  68%  { --seed: 34; }
  70%  { --seed: 35; }
  72%  { --seed: 36; }
  74%  { --seed: 37; }
  76%  { --seed: 38; }
  78%  { --seed: 39; }
  80%  { --seed: 40; }
  82%  { --seed: 41; }
  84%  { --seed: 42; }
  86%  { --seed: 43; }
  88%  { --seed: 44; }
  90%  { --seed: 45; }
  92%  { --seed: 46; }
  94%  { --seed: 47; }
  96%  { --seed: 48; }
  98%  { --seed: 49; }
  100% { --seed: 50; }
}


/* THE ANIMATED OBJECTS */

/* Make div size responsive; apply transition */
div {
  --size: 20vmin;
  font-size: calc(0.15 * var(--size));
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border-radius: var(--size);

  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
/* Show the random number the div is using
 * • Little-end digits define value for `left`
 * • Big-end digits define value for `top`
 */
div::after {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: var(--size);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


div#r1 {
  top: var(--top1);
  left: var(--left1);
  background-color: #900;
  z-index: mod(var(--seed) + 1, 7);
}
div#r1::after {
  content: counter(r1);
}
div#r2 {
  top: var(--top2);
  left: var(--left2);
  background-color: #a60;
  z-index: mod(var(--seed) + 2, 7);
}
div#r2::after {
  content: counter(r2);
}
div#r3 {
  top: var(--top3);
  left: var(--left3);
  background-color: #990;
  z-index: mod(var(--seed) + 3, 7);
}
div#r3::after {
  content: counter(r3);
}
div#r4 {
  top: var(--top4);
  left: var(--left4);
  background-color: #093;
  z-index: mod(var(--seed) + 4, 7);
}
div#r4::after {
  content: counter(r4);
}
div#r5 {
  top: var(--top5);
  left: var(--left5);
  background-color: #059;
  z-index: mod(var(--seed) + 5, 7);
}
div#r5::after {
  content: counter(r5);
}
div#r6 {
  top: var(--top6);
  left: var(--left6);
  background-color: #009;
  z-index: mod(var(--seed) + 6, 7);
}
div#r6::after {
  content: counter(r6);
}
div#r7 {
  top: var(--top7);
  left: var(--left7);
  background-color: #609;
  z-index: mod(var(--seed), 7);
}
div#r7::after {
  content: counter(r7);
}
<main class="lcg">
  <label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label>
  <div id="r1"></div>
  <div id="r2"></div>
  <div id="r3"></div>
  <div id="r4"></div>
  <div id="r5"></div>
  <div id="r6"></div>
  <div id="r7"></div>
</main>



